# Octopus deployment to same environment and different servers

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

I have an octopus deployment that needs to go to a load balanced environment But there are small changes in the config between the two servers.

So, in summary:

- It deploys to the same environment (PreProd)
- It gets deployed to two different servers linked to that environment
- There are small changes between the two web.config files between the two servers.

I already have a `web.preprod.config` that gets transformed into `web.config`. Does it mean I need to create more config files, ie. `web.server1.preprod.config` and `web.server2.preprod.config` or is there another cleaner way of doing it? It is a whole  section that is different so not just an appSetting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that has worked well in similar scenarios for me in the past (with OctopusDeploy specifically), is to use the **web.{environment}.config** transforms to get the correct config **structure** in place, but to use [variable substitution](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Variable+Substitution+Syntax) and define placeholders *in the transform file* to keep the run-time environment-specific definitions in Octopus.  Quite how you break down the substitution syntax is really dependent on your config, but you can use the machine-scoping features of Octopus variables to control the actual values injected.

This scenario is a good example of where web.config transforms start to blur the edges of configuration management; environment-specific config is really the domain of Octopus (or, more specifically, a centralised configuration store), but the solution proposed here is taking it out of Octopus and back into the source repository, which is one of the problems Octopus is actually designed to solve.

For example; what if you introduced a 3rd node in your pre-prod load balancer?  This demands a code change, build, version bump and package, which can be completely avoided given the above.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach to problems like this is, indeed, to create a web.server*.preprod.config, or local.config. I'd suggest looking at what exactly is different in the config, and why. Try to find things that you can merge. For instance:
If one difference is the difference in drive letter, and your config contains these entries:

C:/a/b/c.txt
C:/a/b/d.txt

try splitting those entries into

drive=C
drive:/a/b/c.txt

In that case you only have to change drive=C to drive=D to make two entries work.